# Calling approve function of an erc-20 contract not working

Tags: solidity, remix, erc-20, sepolia

I'm dealing with a problem, I hope someone can help me.

token: 0x9216e1BbC58Ba2bD90c5b49524659209ccaB32Da

contract: 0x8ca112e2fdFF220217609D391eec0B95d5E505a2

alumne: 0xE68Ba7C63B6B94c5beD35B7371F660142211A1ef

owner:0x7E5A0154d04179ed194C96EC9E7A7fe8A378d204

I'm trying to call the approve function by this function:

```
function autoritzarPermisos (address alumne) public {
 require(msg.sender == alumne, "Nomes el compte de l'alumne pot fer l'autoritzacio");


 require(token.balanceOf(msg.sender) >= 1, "No tens prou tokens per autoritzar");


  uint256 tokensAlumne = token.balanceOf(msg.sender);
 token.approve(owner, tokensAlumne);
 token.approve(address(this), tokensAlumne);
}
```

And when I check it on the allowance function from the erc-20 token it shows 0 for both the owner and the contract.

Here's the contract code:

```
    // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.10;

import "./TOKEN.sol"; 

contract SistemaRecompenses {
    JaumeCallisToken public token; 
    address public owner; 
    

    constructor(address tokenAddress) {
        token = JaumeCallisToken(tokenAddress); 
        owner = msg.sender; 
    }

    // Estructura per emmagatzemar les dades de l'alumne
    struct Alumne {
        int256 tokens; 
        uint256 Tokens_Restats_Per_Suspensos_o_Incidencies; 
        uint256 incidencies; 
        uint256 faltes; 
        uint256 retards; 
        uint256 RecompensaBar; 
        uint256 RecompensaSortidaTrimestral; 
        uint256 RecompensaSortidaFinalCurs; 
        uint256 RecompensaBiblioteca;
        uint256 RecompensaTemaClasse;
        
        mapping(string => uint256) assignatures; // Balanç de tokens per assignatura
    }

    mapping(address => Alumne) public alumnes; // Mapping amb les dades de cada alumne
    address[] public adrecesAlumnes; // Llista d'adreces d'alumnes

    //Funció perquè l'alumne cedeixi al contracte i al creador el permís de gestionar els seus tokens actuals
    function autoritzarPermisos (address alumne) public {
     require(msg.sender == alumne, "Nomes el compte de l'alumne pot fer l'autoritzacio");

    // Verifica que l'alumne té almenys 1 token per autoritzar
     require(token.balanceOf(msg.sender) >= 1, "No tens prou tokens per autoritzar");

    // Autoritza el propietari i el contracte per gastar tots els tokens de l'alumne
      uint256 tokensAlumne = token.balanceOf(msg.sender);
     token.approve(owner, tokensAlumne);
     token.approve(address(this), tokensAlumne);
    }

    // Cada alumne s'afageix a la llista 
    function afegirAlumne(address alumne) public {
     require(msg.sender == alumne, "Nomes el compte de l'alumne pot afegir-se a la llista");

     for (uint i = 0; i < adrecesAlumnes.length; i++) {
        require(adrecesAlumnes[i] != alumne, "L'alumne ja existeix a la llista");
    }
    adrecesAlumnes.push(alumne);
    
}
     // Funció per aconseguir el totalSupply 
    function obtenirTotalSupply() public view returns (uint256) {
        require(msg.sender == owner,"Nomes el creador pot executar aquesta funcio");
        return token.totalSupply();
 }

    // Funció perquè l'alumne sumi tokens JC des de l'adreça del creador del contracte
    function transferirTokens(address receiver, uint256 numTokens) public  {
      require(msg.sender == owner,"Nomes el creador pot executar aquesta funcio" );

     token.transferFrom(msg.sender,receiver, numTokens); 
 }
 
    // Funció perquè l'alumne resti tokens i els transfereixi a l'adreça del creador del contracte
    function transferirTokensPerduts(address sender, uint256 numTokens) public {
        require(msg.sender == owner,"Nomes el creador pot executar aquesta funcio" );
         // Verifica que el msg.sender i el contracte tinguin l'autorització necessària per a fer la transferència
        require(token.allowance(sender, msg.sender) >= numTokens, "L'alumne ha de donar la seva autoritzacio previament");
        require(token.allowance(sender, address(this)) >= numTokens, "L'alumne ha de donar la seva autoritzacio previament");
        require(token.balanceOf (sender) >= numTokens, "L'alumne no te suficients tokens");


        // Realitza la transferència des de l'adreça d'origen a l'adreça del que fa la crida (msg.sender)
        require(token.transferFrom(sender, owner, numTokens), "La transferencia ha fallat");
 }
 


    // Funció per iniciar el trimestre i donar 50 tokens a tots els alumnes
    function iniciarTrimestre() public {
    require(msg.sender == owner,"Nomes el creador pot executar aquesta funcio");
   
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < adrecesAlumnes.length; i++) {
        address alumne = adrecesAlumnes[i];
        transferirTokens(alumne, 50*10**18);
        Alumne storage alumneData = alumnes[alumne]; 
        alumneData.tokens += 50; 
        
        // Restableix els valors d'incidències, faltes i retards a 0
        alumneData.incidencies = 0;
        alumneData.faltes = 0;
        alumneData.retards = 0;
    }
}
    // Funció per avaluació de l'alumne
    function avaluarAlumne(address alumne, string memory assignatura, uint256 qualificacio) public {
        require(qualificacio >= 0 && qualificacio <= 10, unicode"Qualificació no vàlida");
        require(msg.sender == owner,"Nomes el creador pot executar aquesta funcio");

        Alumne storage alumneData = alumnes[alumne];

        if (qualificacio >= 9) {
            alumneData.tokens += 10;
            transferirTokens(alumne, 10*10**18);
        } else if (qualificacio >= 7) {
            alumneData.tokens += 5;
            transferirTokens(alumne, 5*10**18);
        } else if (qualificacio < 5) {
            transferirTokensPerduts(alumne, 5*10**18);
                alumneData.tokens -= 5;
                alumneData.Tokens_Restats_Per_Suspensos_o_Incidencies += 5;
            
        }

        
        alumneData.assignatures[assignatura] += uint256 (qualificacio);
    }

    // Funció per registrar una incidència
    function registrarIncidencia(address alumne) public {
        require(msg.sender == owner,"Nomes el creador pot executar aquesta funcio");

        Alumne storage alumneData = alumnes[alumne];

        if (alumneData.incidencies <5) {
            transferirTokensPerduts(alumne, 5*10**18);
                alumneData.tokens -= 5;
                alumneData.Tokens_Restats_Per_Suspensos_o_Incidencies += 5;
            
            
            alumneData.incidencies++;
        } 

        if (alumneData.incidencies >=5)
         require(alumneData.incidencies == 5, "L'alumne ha superat el limit d'incidencies per trimestre");
         transferirTokensPerduts(alumne, 30*10**18);
            alumneData.tokens -= 30;
            alumneData.Tokens_Restats_Per_Suspensos_o_Incidencies += 30;
         
    }
  

    // Funció per registrar una falta
    function registrarFalta(address alumne) public {
        require(msg.sender == owner,"Nomes el creador pot executar aquesta funcio");

        Alumne storage alumneData = alumnes[alumne];

        alumneData.faltes++;

        
        if (alumneData.faltes % 3 == 0) {
            registrarIncidencia(alumne);
        }
    }

    // Funció per registrar un retard
    function registrarRetard(address alumne) public {
        require(msg.sender == owner,"Nomes el creador pot executar aquesta funcio");

        Alumne storage alumneData = alumnes[alumne];

        alumneData.retards++;

        
        if (alumneData.retards % 3 == 0) {
            registrarIncidencia(alumne);
        }
    }

    // Funció per aconseguir les dades d'un alumne
    function obtenirDadesAlumne(address alumne) public view returns (int256 tokens,uint256 Tokens_Restats_Per_Suspensos_o_Incidencies, uint256 incidencies, uint256 faltes, uint256 retards,uint256 RecompensaBar, 
    uint256 RecompensaSortidaTrimestral, uint256 RecompensaSortidaFinalCurs, uint256 RecompensaBiblioteca, uint256 RecompensaTemaClasse) {
        Alumne storage alumneData = alumnes[alumne];
        return (alumneData.tokens, alumneData.Tokens_Restats_Per_Suspensos_o_Incidencies, alumneData.incidencies, alumneData.faltes, alumneData.retards, alumneData.RecompensaBar, alumneData.RecompensaSortidaTrimestral,
        alumneData.RecompensaSortidaFinalCurs, alumneData.RecompensaBiblioteca, alumneData.RecompensaTemaClasse);
    }

    // Funció per canviar recompensa
    function ObtenirRecompensa(address alumne, uint256 opcio) public {
        require(msg.sender == alumne,"Nomes l'alumne pot executar aquesta funcio");
        Alumne storage alumneData = alumnes[alumne];
        require(opcio >= 1 && opcio <= 5, "Opcio no valida");

        
        uint8[5] memory preus = [20, 0, 0, 60, 60];

        require(int256 (alumneData.tokens) >= int8 (preus[opcio - 1]), "Tokens insuficients");

        alumneData.tokens -= int8 (preus[opcio - 1]);

        // Aplica la recompensa segons l'opció triada
        if (opcio == 1) {
            // Descompte al bar
            // Conversió de 20 JCTokens = 1 euro
            alumneData.RecompensaBar += 1;
            token.approve(owner, type(uint256).max);
            token.approve(address(this), type(uint256).max);
            transferirTokensPerduts(alumne, 20*10**18);
        } else if (opcio == 2) {
            // Assistència a sortida escolar (màxim 30 JCTokens restats)
            require(alumneData.Tokens_Restats_Per_Suspensos_o_Incidencies <= 30, "Has restat masses tokens, no pots participar a la sortida");
            alumneData.RecompensaSortidaTrimestral += 1;
        } else if (opcio == 3) {
            // Assistència a sortida de final de curs (màxim 120 JCTokens restats)
            require(alumneData.Tokens_Restats_Per_Suspensos_o_Incidencies <= 120, "Has restat masses tokens, no pots participar a la sortida");
            alumneData.RecompensaSortidaFinalCurs += 1;
        } else if (opcio == 4) {
            // Permis per anar a la biblioteca durant els patis (60 JCTokens)
            alumneData.RecompensaBiblioteca += 1;
            token.approve(owner, type(uint256).max);
            token.approve(address(this), type(uint256).max);
            transferirTokensPerduts(alumne, 60*10**18);
        } else if (opcio == 5) {
            // Triar el tema de classe d'una tutoria (60 JCTokens)
            alumneData.RecompensaTemaClasse += 1;
            token.approve(owner, type(uint256).max);
            token.approve(address(this), type(uint256).max);
            transferirTokensPerduts(alumne, 60*10**18);
        } 
    }


    // Funció per canviar recompensa (aquesta seria la funció que cridaria algun professor o encarregat del bar per gastar la recompensa de l'alumne)
    function UtilitzarRecompensa(address alumne, uint256 opcio) public {
        require(msg.sender == alumne,"Nomes l'alumne pot executar aquesta funcio");
        Alumne storage alumneData = alumnes[alumne];
        require(opcio >= 1 && opcio <= 5, unicode"Opció no vàlida");

        if (opcio == 1) {
            // Descompte al bar
            // Conversió de 20 JCTokens = 1 euro
            require(alumneData.RecompensaBar >=1,"Obten primer la recompensa");
            alumneData.RecompensaBar -= 1;
        } else if (opcio == 2) {
            require(alumneData.RecompensaSortidaTrimestral >=1,"Obten primer la recompensa");
            alumneData.RecompensaSortidaTrimestral -= 1;
        } else if (opcio == 3) {
            // Assistència a sortida de final de curs (mínim 120 JCTokens)
            require(alumneData.RecompensaSortidaFinalCurs >=1,"Obten primer la recompensa");
            alumneData.RecompensaSortidaFinalCurs -= 1;
        } else if (opcio == 4) {
            // Permis per anar a la biblioteca durant els patis (60 JCTokens)
            require(alumneData.RecompensaBiblioteca >=1,"Obten primer la recompensa");
            alumneData.RecompensaBiblioteca -= 1;
        } else if (opcio == 5) {
            // Triar el tema de classe d'una tutoria (60 JCTokens)
            require(alumneData.RecompensaTemaClasse >=1,"Obten primer la recompensa");
            alumneData.RecompensaTemaClasse -= 1;
        } 
    }
}
```

And here the token code:

```
    // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.10;

interface IERC20 {

    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);

    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);


    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}


contract JaumeCallisToken is IERC20 {
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    string public constant name = "JaumeCallisToken";
    string public constant symbol = "JC";
    uint8 public constant decimals = 18;

    mapping(address => uint256) balances;
    mapping(address => mapping (address => uint256)) allowed;

    uint256 private totalSupply_ = 21000000*10**uint256(decimals);

    constructor(){
        balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply_;
    }

    function totalSupply() public override view returns (uint256) {
        return totalSupply_;
    }

    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public override view returns (uint256) {
        return balances[tokenOwner];
    }


    function transfer(address receiver, uint256 numTokens) public override returns (bool) {

        require(numTokens <= balances[msg.sender]);
        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(numTokens);
        balances[receiver] = balances[receiver].add(numTokens);
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, receiver, numTokens);
        return true;

    }

    function approve(address delegate, uint256 numTokens) public override returns (bool) {
        allowed[msg.sender][delegate] = numTokens;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, delegate, numTokens);
        return true;
    }

    function allowance(address owner, address delegate) public override view returns (uint) {
        return allowed[owner][delegate];
    }

    function transferFrom(address owner, address buyer, uint256 numTokens) public override returns (bool) {

        require(numTokens <= balances[owner]);
        require(numTokens <= allowed[owner][msg.sender]);

        balances[owner] = balances[owner].sub(numTokens);
        allowed[owner][msg.sender] = allowed[owner][msg.sender].sub(numTokens);
        balances[buyer] = balances[buyer].add(numTokens);
        emit Transfer(owner, buyer, numTokens);
        return true;

    }
}

library SafeMath {
    function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
      assert(b <= a);
      return a - b;
    }

    function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
      uint256 c = a + b;
      assert(c >= a);
      return c;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the code above the contract (0x8ca112e2fdFF220217609D391eec0B95d5E505a2) gave approval to the owner (0x7E5A0154d04179ed194C96EC9E7A7fe8A378d204) and to itself (0x8ca112e2fdFF220217609D391eec0B95d5E505a2) to spend tokens that belong to the contract. See the events from the actual transaction in the attached image.

It is not possible for the contract to give approval for spending someone else's tokens. The user must run approve transaction separately. Or as an alternative the user can transfer tokens to the contract first and now the contract will own them and can approve others to spend these tokens.
[image]

Comment: So, there's no way for the user to give approval to the owner and the contract by firing a function in the contract?

Comment: no. Only the owner of ERC20 tokens can execute approve transaction for these tokens